# What are possible vanishing sets of real analytic functions?

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-geometry

I know that an analytic function from R to R cannot vanish on a set with accumulation points. Is it true in general that the set of zeroes of an analytic function from R^n to R (or possibly a collection of such functions) have some nice characterization?

My best guess is that such sets have to be 'locally algebraic', ie for every x the intersection of the set with some neighborhood U of x is the intersection of some algebraic set with U. But this seems almost too good to be true... Does anyone know an answer or a place I might look?

Comment: Some people have devoted their lives to characterizing the zero sets of polynomials so, while I'm not an expert, I wouldn't bet on any really strong results about analytic functions.

Answer (score 1):

Locally algebraic?  Try $f(x,y) = y - e^x$.  Its zero set is the graph of $y = e^x$, which is certainly not algebraic.